# Facebook plugins slow page load - what can be done to improve this?

Tags: performance, flags, social-network

I currently use the Facebook plugin integration module, and have a like button and a fb comment block on each page. Especially the FB plugins load slow.
It appears that any link on the page is not clickable until the whole page including fb plugins have loaded...currently about 5 seconds per page (!)

I was thinking about using a simple link with (rules link form example, or flag with flag field) to trigger the fb like and comment plugins in the background. Would anyting like that be possible?

Comment: Sounds like a frontend issue. Can you use hook_js_alter to make the js load async or defer?